# I get an EXTJS warning that the json data is incorrect

Tags: json, extjs

My data looks like this.

```
{
  "total": "5",
  "data": [
    {
      "Id": "5141",
      "Qty": "1",
      "Year": "175",
      "Country": "GREAT BRITAN",
      "Denomination": "HALF PENNY",
      "Grade": "Uncirculated",
      "Mint": "",
      "Value": "5.00",
      "Obversa": "",
      "Reverse": "",
      "Comments": "",
      "PurchaseDate": "2010-11-05 00:00:00",
      "CoinTotal": "5.00"
    },
    {
      "Id": "5141",
      "Qty": "1",
      "Year": "175",
      "Country": "GREAT BRITAN",
      "Denomination": "HALF PENNY",
      "Grade": "Fair",
      "Mint": "",
      "Value": "5.00",
      "Obversa": "",
      "Reverse": "",
      "Comments": "",
      "PurchaseDate": "2010-11-05 00:00:00",
      "CoinTotal": "5.00"
    },
    {
      "Id": "5141",
      "Qty": "1",
      "Year": "175",
      "Country": "GREAT BRITAN",
      "Denomination": "HALF PENNY",
      "Grade": "Very Fine",
      "Mint": "",
      "Value": "5.00",
      "Obversa": "",
      "Reverse": "",
      "Comments": "",
      "PurchaseDate": "2010-11-05 00:00:00",
      "CoinTotal": "5.00"
    },
    {
      "Id": "5141",
      "Qty": "1",
      "Year": "175",
      "Country": "GREAT BRITAN",
      "Denomination": "HALF PENNY",
      "Grade": "PROOF",
      "Mint": "",
      "Value": "5.00",
      "Obversa": "",
      "Reverse": "",
      "Comments": "",
      "PurchaseDate": "2010-11-05 00:00:00",
      "CoinTotal": "5.00"
    },
    {
      "Id": "5141",
      "Qty": "1",
      "Year": "175",
      "Country": "GREAT BRITAN",
      "Denomination": "HALF PENNY",
      "Grade": "Good",
      "Mint": "",
      "Value": "5.00",
      "Obversa": "",
      "Reverse": "",
      "Comments": "",
      "PurchaseDate": "2010-11-05 00:00:00",
      "CoinTotal": "5.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

However I still get this error

> [WARN] Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server.

Can someone identify the error and correction?

Comment: Correct grammar and format code

Comment: I don't recall if EXTJS requires unique IDs... do you have your data model?